Question about a solution to IMO 1993 p2.
Here is the problem from the contest:
Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(1)=2$ and $f(f(n))=f(n)+n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(n)<f(n+1)$

In this post the OP answered his own question by proving his claim that $f(n)=\lfloor \phi n +\frac{1}{2}\rfloor$. The part that confuses me why is it required that $$X(n)=\phi\lfloor\phi n + \frac{1}{2}\rfloor+\frac{1}{2}-\lfloor\phi n +\frac{1}{2}\rfloor-n=(\phi-1)\lfloor \phi n +\frac{1}{2}\rfloor+\frac{1}{2}-n$$
must be between $0 \leq X(n)<1$ ? I suspect that it has something to do with the fraction part but I'm still clueless...

That is because $ f(f(n)) - f(n) - n = \lfloor X(n) \rfloor$ (this wasn't explicitly defined, it's the "suffices to prove" step). To prove that $f(n)$ is a valid solution (satisfies the functional equation), we need to show that $ \lfloor X(n) \rfloor = 0$, or that $ 0 \leq X_n < 1$.
